# Don't output the file

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, open-ended-function

[This `rar` file](https://www.cfresh.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/8200912819148.rar), when decompressed, gives a 65024-byte `exe` file. Requiring you to output the contents of that file would be absolutely no fun.

But you aren't required to do that. Actually, you're to do something opposite: Output a binary of the same length (65024 bytes), such that no byte equals the byte at same position in the source `exe` file.

This is code-golf, shortest code wins.

Comment: Should the binary work when used?

Comment: The binary is the `rar` file itself, not the extracted contents, right?

Comment: What makes this challenge interesting? A compressed file will look almost purely random, so there doesn't seem to be a strategy to avoid byte values

Comment: @pxeger `

This is a quite compressed 65024-byte exe file.`

Comment: @LuisMendo Find a way to avoid most and hardcode the rest ones. It'd be hundreds of bytes so optimizing the avoidment matter

Comment: Any reason why you have a rar with exe? Why not just the raw 65,024 bytes?

Comment: @l4m2 Responding to my request for clarification with a quote from the question which I can read in front of me doesn't help. I can already read that, and it wasn't clear enough to answer my query. I think I have worked out what you meant by looking at the file sizes of the `rar` and the `exe` (the extracted `exe` is 65024 bytes, but the `rar` is 64848), but I'm still not sure. Can you please explicitly clarify the question?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that [VirusTotal flags the `exe` as possible malware](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/2b6f58ba715909be1d1276a3f93442421c2a20d89cb1188e6b5d2b7bca840e97/detection). I think this is just a false positive because the file is so compressed that it looks like encryption, which is potentially suspicious for an `exe`, but I still don't suggest running it.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear for the reasons stated by @pxeger

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's already online I needn't reupload

Comment: @pxeger a quite compressed 65024-byte ***exe*** file.

Comment: When I download the file, it is only 64848 bytes.  Not sure if that matters?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Although I won't blame you because the OP has still refused to be explicit about it, you need to extract the `rar` file to get the `exe`, which is the file in question.

Comment: @l4m2 I edited to clarify. If my changes conflict with your intentions, feel free to roll back the edit and make your own edit instead.

Answer (score 6):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 81 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
•Out 65024↑1042/"#?ZY>Rg*778c0?74h3g)G?mm5963!1[!1OC+VUb)7]#Z-%&N/D^sUrJaVwc}%! "
```

[Try it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=NjUwMjTihpExMDQyLyIjP1pZPlJnKjc3OGMwPzc0aDNnKUc/bW01OTYzITFbITFPQytWVWIpN10jWi0lJk4vRF5zVXJKYVZ3Y30lISAi) This is written for [CBQN](https://github.com/dzaima/CBQN), I removed the `•Out`  to run it online.

If you split the binary into chunks of 1042, in each chunk at least one printable different from `"` is missing. Search program:

```
pa ← @-˜'"'⊸≠⊸/' '+↕95
b ← @-˜•FBytes "fr08v101.exe"
m ← ⊑⌽1000+/{⊑∧´¬∧˝pa∊⌜<˘↑‿⥊b}¨ 1000+↕1000
•Show m
•Show @+⊑⟜pa¨ ⊑∘/˘⍉¬pa∊⌜<˘↑‿m⥊b
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```
<3s*L1586"iýy±å7Ë±â7a£Õ§³mh79B!OÈ­wc7wÝ%'÷î3awo÷c­#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUwAs/9weXRo//88M3MqTDE1ODYiacO9ecKxw6U3w4vCscOiN2HCo8OVwqfCs21oNzlCIU/DiMKtd2M3d8OdJSfDt8OuM2F3b8O3Y8KtI///)

```
         "iýy±å7Ë±â7a£Õ§³mh79B!OÈ­wc7wÝ%'÷î3awo÷c­#    41-character string literal
   *L1586                                            repeat each character 1586 times
  s                                                  concatenate
<3                                                   remove the last 3 characters
                                                     output with a trailing newline
```

(Use the `PYTHONIOENCODING=latin1` environment variable for correct binary output.)

Comment: I feel like the requirement of the environment variable should cost bytes.

Comment: @Makonede The environment variable is not required; it just changes the output format to bytes for more convenient verification. The output without it is still correct, just in a different format (65024 UTF-8 characters), exactly like l4m2’s own JavaScript answer and similarly to the answers that return an array of 65024 integers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 339 bytes

```
ＵＴＩ⪪”}⊞➙×Ｔμ[j…｜U◨{Ｕ⁸→º4Ｄ›⮌⪫ιaＹh⎇E"6ºρ⌊mＭＯk…÷›ＧF⭆B↨⬤U↙⊕✳…Ｈd¶5‖Ｏ$¬÷Ｇ≕6ＴχSυ⟧⌈◨~a3j'▷↘3⊖À⁷0r]e⎇⁻≔s＆g>▶r↔⊗⁰ηχκη↔S1hLΦ⍘⦄⪪⊕«⪪⊙M»nＰＯgbＯ\XＫÀ›'◨‽⬤κ➙›\p；▶⸿⁴P÷χ>Ie…Ｅσ/Ｎ⟲Ｂ÷«～υ⟧χ9✂‽G⁶⦄⁷τＨ¿Þ₂⊘ΦＷ4rO＆v×σIB⍘↔_﹪ηA⸿/?⊙/Ｊ¡lβ“K▷¬✂6τＢ﹪G▶﹪⁺%zÀτ(&7\`g⁷Ｃ↙¤⦄ïＧ↖0⪫ςj]nＱ#Ｗ¶ＪeM)⬤χ9c←@⁷S5w⌊#Ｕ；Ｎ⌕·NＳＮ1?Σ@s↖$Ｔ(⁵xd«Fαh▶º⌊0l⮌d⮌oＨ"=d=▷À⁰j¤q⊙⦃Oε↥∧ψ�¬&≧↷cy/⊞⁴GE»¦≔✳κ¦'⁶↘S⎚ü]₂Ｑ”¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZPBbhsxDETv/YrCJxtogSUpiRJy7A8UaI57MYIiDeBuAtfo77t81LoHy5JIDYfD2Zdf5@vL@/lyvz@/v75efj5f334fT0@fvl/fttvx2/nP7fjj4/J2Ox5kKbJuw9etqq6bSFnWzWKn2tetSATUYumkidZYlhaBXmJX42jrFmdpsXj8jKhoA3AJhN5H7Aysyq7EkwFKpPWAVO8ARVFxqsoAY8AEIqRLKRSMYMty1YnUyG4OC6nUiqV4APYF1Ep6ZAxexbPW@g6kc4lEdyrHocMFCcwMvEg12QkZqXmd9BaI0gH/La6RS0fSDxB4CbQblCCHPKjEvgSbQh0pD8DiEYS2UVUl0nxEcFC/pIhxMJqbmqEDuhlZKRHkaMU7odRLdzxZegK2h8RIkXo5A8pkGcGq9TiWRkomQ1tTp747Id3xf/xK287o2oJD6CB1k4FcDKqo0PojwNywCKCZyCyj8mjM2mZRm72Je17WvU11z7moz5aZvyYy6pn2OceBdxC7sDgkOu/QYNi05TTfSFtEzJBh4pa9PU2jIQe2V9F9EOJpI4ihzHT@7CRHAx2@G0ZrBsPpvpoA07nMXpFaZDdVmR1Jn@5Rnz9/dAp17rEReYAtyJTT2P2XHWo2ju60NcVVeEAP@1laXSar/MKZslFuZFfwoT8FRmt@FNOAgpV1MTl8@XxYt8PpdHq63@9f/17@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal is very good at printing lots of `-` signs. The compressed strings represents all the runs of non-`-`-signs in the file. Each run of `-`s is separated by a newline, thus ensuring that no character of the output matches a character in the file.

```
ＵＴ
```

Turn off Charcoal's default rectangular output, since we don't want space padding.

```
Ｉ⪪...¶
```

Split the compressed string `1041\n97...104\n2031` on newlines (they are the golfiest separators), and cast the numbers to integer, which causes Charcoal to output them as that number of `-` signs.

A "port" of @ovs's answer is only 90 bytes:

```
⭆“"jＶXＷ⬤tＯ#^S0➙↷⊟Li§Ｋ″1·β℅±d74%;{ESＭ»ΠⅈρξDςΦcＳEenÞ⁻.⁷¡ê；q¬⟧l﹪Π0№Σ″≔Ｘ⁼·⁶d´Z»～⪪Ｖ⎚+⪪ÀkＯ”×ι⁵¹²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzdCsIwDIVfZUnXdnVrhoI3K7InEAS9WxDGEB3MH@bwRvDVawrhhJNz8g23fh6e/RTjYR4fS3FcZF33/atARsXYehFFVMLKMzrqNO1AUWAE0oyVzcUxMxIxetMCY2lVWXeglbYgNg2ApCrUtRVaTtQwGuXTLeENkXSN8RZsJ@1GfV35C4lpmOX/DA04rYkIq@w03i/vYqyy7XrjnAsxRv@Z/g) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Simply repeats each character in the compressed string 512 times (I used this instead of @ovs' 1042 because it's a factor of 65024 and larger factors end up covering all of printable ASCII). Conveniently all the characters needed are in Charcoal's "symbols" area which allows the string to be compressed from 127 to 84 bytes. (It's not possible to do this with all letters (either upper or lower case) or all digits.)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES10), 131 bytes

Returns an array of bytes.

```javascript
_=>[..."hx53ptn9mgv1xij4xcw506nhi1cxi7w116o3kntsesafc5xwy4w15u6bo7ulphwt"].flatMap(v=>Array(1016).fill(n-=parseInt(v,36)-17),n=187)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRDoIgFADQf@kl2JR5Z2I90NZjD31Ba41IFKMLEwL8ejtnlkkGtRgfa3TvYdNie4rznTG2m0rX@oin75igmPlQVO4ajpMBVUyfAbhrPxjDEKRWXcnrIUP34y/X/6yfctw9mLYy3qQnSZwvyyJXAg1wyrSxlmAtvFzCcMVIUtVyWkNPKxRw7OmmHAZnB2bdSDShbHYGyb7aU7r9AQ)

#### How?

This encodes 64 bytes \$b_0\$ to \$b_{63}\$ that are repeated 1016 times each and do not appear in the corresponding chunk of the original file:

```javascript
187,171,183,197,189,177,171,179,174,175,161,177,161,160,158,171,
155,160,145,157,174,185,179,179,178,194,199,183,182,192,177,193,
209,220,213,227,224,218,206,195,198,187,194,196,201,213,197,182,
165,178,163,179,191,178,189,195,188,198,185,181,173,173,158,146
```

The values were chosen in such a way that \$|b_k-b_{k-1}|<18\$ for each \$k>0\$, which allows to store the delta values in base 36.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>260</s> <s>70</s> 69 bytes

*-1 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
•Ý=£ë—ÛāR5Bf·½"¨ß¡˜v`₆BÌÝΩ\∞?ΓтJ&тƒFćO#'œ|Ć‹RÞ¼Á,нìçD|•Ƶ?вŽ4´δи˜Ž3ć(£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AYAAf/9vc2FiaWX//@KAosOdPcKjw6vigJTDm8SBUjVCZsK3wr0iwqjDn8Khy5x2YOKChkLDjMOdzqlc4oieP86T0YJKJtGCxpJGxIdPIyfFk3zEhuKAuVLDnsK8w4Es0L3DrMOnRHzigKLGtT/QssW9NMK0zrTQuMucxb0zxIcowqP//w) Outputs as a list of byte values. [Alternative link](https://tio.run/##AYMAfP9vc2FiaWX//@KAosOdPcKjw6vigJTDm8SBUjVCZsK3wr0iwqjDn8Khy5x2YOKChkLDjMOdzqlc4oieP86T0YJKJtGCxpJGxIdPIyfFk3zEhuKAuVLDnsK8w4Es0L3DrMOnRHzigKLGtT/QssW9NMK0zrTQuMucxb0zxIcowqP/w6dK/w) for text output.

## Explanation

Similarly to other answers here, this answer uses equal-sized chunks (except the last chunk), each consisting of the same byte throughout the entire chunk (but different bytes throughout the entire output). To get an optimal score, maximizing the chunk size is important – or rather, minimizing the number of chunks.

To do this, I iterated through chunk sizes, starting from \$1{,}000\$ and going up. With each iteration, I checked if every byte value was present at least once in at least one chunk.

This happened at \$1{,}200\$ bytes per chunk. This meant that each chunk but the last can be up to \$1{,}199\$ bytes, with the last chunk being \$278\$ bytes. This means there are \$54\$ full chunks plus the small chunk at the end, making a total of \$55\$ chunks.

Let's verify this: \$54×1{,}199+278=65{,}024\$.

Finally, for each chunk, we find the smallest byte that doesn't exist there and repeat it for the length of that chunk, and we're done!

Comment: `εŽ4´и}` to `Ž4´δи` for -1.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 74 bytes SBCS

```javascript
_=>"­[-!^7q7hŒƒŽÏ³á»±™{3Ž³îg}GÅc¬ïn·×O~v#¹›½+:[¦w".repeat(1414).slice(20)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AYUAev9qYXZhc2NyaXB0LW5vZGX/Zj3/Xz0@IsKtWy0hXjdxN2jCjMKDwo7Dj8Kzw6HCu8Kxwpl7M8KOwrPDrmd9R8OFY8Ksw69uwrfDl09@diMVwrnCm8K9KzpbwqZ3Ii5yZXBlYXQoMTQxNCkuc2xpY2UoMjAp/2NvbnNvbGUubG9nKGYoKSn/)

I'm not sure if this happen for random enough file, or why you use `aaaabbbbccccdddd` rather than `abcdabcdabcdabcd` even for languages with better support for the latter solution

Comment: I haven't tried the `abcdabcd...` pattern for my answer, but it only has a longer lookup string because I limited myself to printable ascii. If I'd use the full byte range, I could use a length 41 string, which is shorter than the one used here. I guess in Javascript repeating each character is a lot longer, so your approach is probably better.

Comment: @ovs Using printable ascii, the minimum loop length is 76

Answer (score 0):

PHP (276 chars)

```php
for($d=[-17,-532,-95,-515,-79,463,95,-392,-27,148,$i=-1,808,53,61,15,-665,-5,419,-29,211,46,399,95,569,11,-2,101,-588,11,418,-43,-70,-48,-1887,105,918,-63,-1655,-97,-317,-104,-116,-74,513,53,885,-97,605,150,593,20,-295];++$i<52;)echo str_repeat(chr(150-$d[$i]),2500-$d[++$i]);
```

[Try it Online](https://link.gy/4bb85) *(using an URL shortener to store the **.exe** file)*

If [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) is available it's **206 chars** long :

```php
for($d=str_split(($i=0).gmp_init('1FmB6eDs41MlblmT1hchbcMok3RFjcIJ7OHt8hphdLMPDPgigsPrqHXfc3QEFotYuvL9zfZ3y7ZYkD7nnoSCgAzgJhHEVnl9R6mB5cshIudtpnunsccV',62),4);$i<52;)echo str_repeat(chr($d[$i++]),$d[$i++]);
```

**How is generated this sequence of [str_repeat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) ?**

Just by the output of [strcspn](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php).

```php
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('raw_file');
$file_length = strlen($data);
$ptr = 0;
while ($ptr < $file_length) {
    $max_dist = $max_ord = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 256; ++$i) {
        $char = chr($i);
        $dist = strcspn($data, $char, $ptr);
        if ($dist > $max_dist) {
            $max_dist = $dist;
            $max_ord = $i;
        }
    }
    $ptr += $max_dist;
    echo ".str_repeat(chr($max_ord), $max_dist)";
}
```